How do I find a duplicate in a Java array?
public class Unidad_6 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean dupl = false;
        int arreglo[] = new int[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.length;
            i++){
            arreglo[i] = entrada.nextInt();

        }

        for (int i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
            for (int j=0 ; j<arreglo.length; j++){
                if (arreglo[i] == arreglo[j] ){
                    dupl = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When I find a duplicate within an array it throws boolean true despite it being false.

Your inner loop compares each int against all other ints — including itself. For example, you'll check to see if arreglo[0] == arreglo[0]. The linked answer has the solution, but I strongly urge you to learn how to use a debugger, and/or to debug by hand using pencil and paper. If you don't learn on these relatively easy tasks, it will be much harder to learn when you get to the more complicated ones.

The very first time through the second for loop both I and j are equal to zero so you are comparing the first element with itself.

How do I find a duplicate question among the millions of questions on Stack Overflow? ;-) Use your search engine. Welcome to Stack Overflow.
